Fixed effect in cross-border discontinuity approach: include both county fixed effect and state border fixed effect?
The cross-border discontinuity approach in concern uses state-wide events that are introduced into states in a staggered manner and involves county-level GDP as the dependent variable. I am wondering whether I should only account for the county-level fixed effect? Or should I account for both county-level fixed effect and state-border fixed effect? I am esp. wondering about whether I should additionally include state-border fixed effect because some counties locate on different state borders at the same time (e.g. Bowie County in Texas borders two states besides Texas). However, I think the point still stands that such an effect might have also absorbed into the county-level fixed effects already.

Once a state “event” is in effect does it affect all counties within the state?

I am quite sure that it a state effect would affect all counties within the state.
